# storageos ls: cannot access 'volumes': Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: kubernetes, storage, coreos

I am trying to clean up and redeploy storageos but somehow I got to this weird error.

```
slave1 storageos # pwd
/var/lib/storageos
slave1 storageos # ls -la
ls: cannot access 'volumes': Transport endpoint is not connected
total 24
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root 4096 Jan 31 19:36 .
drwxr-xr-x. 35 root root 4096 Feb  1 00:00 ..
drwx------.  6 root root 4096 Jan 31 19:22 data
d??????????  ? ?    ?       ?            ? volumes
slave1 storageos # rm -rf volumes 
rm: cannot remove 'volumes': Is a directory
slave1 storageos # uname -a
Linux slave1 4.14.88-coreos #1 SMP Mon Jan 7 23:48:02 -00 2019 x86_64 Intel(R) Atom(TM) x5-Z8330 CPU @ 1.44GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
slave1 storageos #
```

Any suggestions how to eliminate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually manually umounting this dir eliminates this error

```
slave3 storageos # df
df: /var/lib/storageos/volumes: Transport endpoint is not connected
Filesystem      1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs           964768       0    964768   0% /dev
tmpfs              985804       0    985804   0% /dev/shm
...
slave3 storageos # umount /var/lib/storageos/volumes
slave3 storageos # df
Filesystem      1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs           964768       0    964768   0% /dev
tmpfs              985804       0    985804   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs              985804     984    984820   1% /run
...
```